# Multiple Resources in a Collection

Tags: apigee

In the API Managment console, it is possible to put multiple resources in a single Proxy.  Is that same capability available for App Services?  I'd like to put multiple resources in a single collection.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an api proxy you create a basepath (like /v1).  You can then add resources within that group (/v1/resource).

See http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/add-and-configure-your-first-api